# Field Question Proof with Axiom 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Prove that if $(F,+,⋅,0,1)$ is a field, then there is no element $w ∈ F$ such that $0 \cdot w = 1$.

Note that Axiom 4 from lecture (aka "M4" in the textbook) ensures that for $x ≠ 0$, there is a $w ∈ F$ so that $x⋅w=1$, but it does not rule out, on its own, the possibility that there is some $w ∈ F$ so that $0⋅w=1$ (i.e., the answer is not "Axiom 4 states $x ≠ 0$, so were done.")

Axiom 4:
 given $x$, there is a $w \in S$
     such that $x + w = 0$

for $x$ cannot be $0$, there is $w \in S$ such that $x \cdot w = 1$.

I think to do this proof we have to prove $0 \cdot w = 0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: In rings $0\cdot w = 0$, so in this case you have $0 = 1$ which isn't a field.

Answer (score 1):

Well suppose that $0\cdot w = 1$ and and that $1 \neq 0$.

$$(0+0)\cdot w = 0\cdot w + 0 \cdot w = 1+1$$
$$(0+0) \cdot w = 0\cdot w = 1$$

$$1 = 1+1 \Rightarrow 1 = 0$$

And we have a contradiction, as we assumed that this was not a trivial field.

Answer (score 0):

Note the lemma that $0x=0$ for all $x\in F$ implies this. For a (sketch of a) proof:

$0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$, then subtract $0x$ to get $0x-0x=0x+0x-0x$, then $0=0x+0$, then $0=0x$.

I leave it up to you to fill in the axioms.